# DynamoDB : Global Secondary Index utilisation in queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I am coming from RDMS background and I started using DynamoDB recently.

I have following DyamoDB table with three Global Secondary Indexes (GSI)

> Id (**primary key**), user_id(**GSI**), event_type (**GSI**), product_id (**GSI**)
>   , rate, create_date

I have following three query patterns:

- a) WHERE event_type=?
- b) WHERE event_type=? AND product_id=?
- c) WHERE product_id=?
- d) WHERE product_id=? AND user_id=?

I know in MySQL I need to create following indexes to optimize above queries :

- composite index (event_type,product_id) : for queries "a" and "b"
- composite index (product_id,user_id) : for queries "c" and "d"

My question is , if I create three GSIs for 'event_type', 'product_id' and 'user_id' fields in DyanomoDB, do the query patterns "b" and "d" utilize these three independent GSIs ?

Comment: Is DynamoDB based on indexedDB? indexedDB is an embedded database supported by browsers and accessible by Javascript. If your question isn't related to that, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, unlike in RDBMS, the Dynamodb doesn't choose the GSI based on the fields used in filter expression (I meant there is no SQL optimizer to choose the appropriate index based on the fields used in SQL).

You will have to query the GSI directly to get the data. You can refer the GSI query page to understand more on this.

You can create two GSIs:-

1) Event type

2) Product id

You make sure to include the other required fields in the GSI especially product id, user id and any other required fields. This way when you query the GSI, you get all the fields required to fulfill the use case. As long as you have one field from GSI, you can include other fields in Filter expression to filter the data. This ensures that you dont create unnecessary GSIs which requires additional space and cost.