# Dynamodb GSI query: what role sort key plays

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have been reading questions about best way to use a GSI and this one [DynamoDB : Global Secondary Index utilisation in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900963/dynamodb-global-secondary-index-utilisation-in-queries) came close to what I need but I still have a few questions.

I have a scenario where I have product table with fields:

```
product_id (partitions_key), product_name, launch_year, manufacturer
```

I need to make the following three types of queries:

```
1. product_name=?
2. product_name=? AND launch_year=?
3. product_name=? AND manufacturer=?
```

From my understanding creating one GSI based on product_name will server all 3 purposes.
What I want to understand is that will adding 2 more GSI with launch_year and manufacturer as the sort keys speed up query 2 and 3? Is the sole purpose of sort key to return sorted data or will Dynamodb query somehow take advantage of the fact that the field of interest is sorted?

Comment: probably you want to read about binary search

Comment: So I assume dynamodb query uses binary search and not linear search in this scenario?

Comment: yes, this is the only purpose of the indexes: create sorted duplicate to avoid full scan

Comment: I understand that for the hash key, I was specifically asking about the sort key in GSI

Comment: they both serve the same purpose, but differently, hash (partition) key is mostly to distribute work across nodes, sort keys to speed up look ups/scans

Comment: with hash key you have getbyid operation with avg O(1), but you cannot use range conditions efficiently, with sorted table you have getbyid O(logN), but range conditions are efficient, dynamodb is key value storage, so main optimization is for getbyid, this is why partition key is required, as additional feature they provide sorted secondary indexes

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create two more indexes. The reasons are:-

1. It will add additional cost. Having multiple GSIs will cost you for read and write capacity units
2. Also, for the above 2 use cases, it is not required. You can use `FilterExpressions` to filter the data by `launch_year` and `manufacturer`
3. Another option is to have only one GSI with `product_name` and `launch_year`. So you are covered with 2 use cases. For the 3rd use case, you can use `FilterExpression`
4. In all these options, you can still use Query API as you have the partition key `product_name`

Comment: Thanks. Cost point of view makes sense. #3 is a smart idea I'll think about it.

Comment: @notionquest for #3 i.e having GSI on product_name and launch_year (composite), if few of my records have null launch_year and non null product_name. I think while querying on this GSI table using only product_name will not fetch me the record which is having null launch_year. As dynamo won't populate this record to GSI table. Please  correct me.